# Eclipse template for setter that calls firePropertyChange()

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-templates

For MVC model classes, my setters look like:

```
enum BoundProperty {FIELD_NAME, ...}

private Type fieldName;

public setFieldName(Type newValue) {
    Type oldValue = fieldName;
    fieldName = newValue;
    firePropertyChange(BoundProperty.FIELD_NAME, oldValue, newValue);
}
```

Given a field, can this output be produced from the autogenerated setter?  If not is there a way to get this output from a template?

The output should CamelCase the field name to produce the method name, so fieldName generates setFieldName() and Uppercase the field name to produce the property enum.

So fieldName generates `FIELD_NAME` (or `FIELDNAME` would work too).

Comment: It looks like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7237108/274350) does some of what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is not a straightforward way to make this through Eclipse templates, mainly regarding the camelCase/upperCase and generation of enum values. You can check these two questions [Is there a way to capitalize the first letter of a value of a variable in Eclipse (Helios) code templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664989/is-there-a-way-to-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-a-value-of-a-variable-in-eclips), [Programmatically add code templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882191/programmatically-add-code-templates) to dig into further details.

IMHO, the best way to achieve what you want is to use the [Fast Code Eclipse Plugin](http://fast-code.sourceforge.net/) and write a velocity template for that plugin that generates all the code from the fields.

```
enum BoundProperty {
#foreach ($field in ${fields})
    ${field.toUpperCase()} #if( $foreach.hasNext ), #end
#end
}

#foreach ($field in ${fields})
    public ${field.type} get${field.name.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()}${field.name.substring(1)}(${field.type} newValue) {
        Type oldValue = fieldName;
        fieldName = newValue;
        firePropertyChange(BoundProperty.${field.name.toUpperCase()}, oldValue, newValue);       
    }
#end
```

Or change the ["getter_setter" template of that plugin](http://fast-code.sourceforge.net/getter-setter.html).

Answer (score 1):

I can see this message on "Generate getters/setters" dialog. 
*The format of the getters/setters may be configured on the Code Templates preference page.* You can go there (`Setter Body` under `Code` section) and modify like below.

```
Type oldValue = ${field};
${field} = ${param};
firePropertyChange(BoundProperty.FIELD_NAME, oldValue, ${param});
```

However it is not going to generate `BoundProperty` though. It need more research to find out if it is possible or not. These links may help

[Useful Eclipse Java Code Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028858/useful-eclipse-java-code-templates) and
[Getting started with Eclipse code templates](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-eclipse-code-templates/section4.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried this, but it's not enough - Type should be the type of the field, and FIELD_NAME should be the uppercase version of the fieldName.  There doesn't seem to be a way to derive these from the variables available in the Code Templates screen?

Comment: I have just added some links in the answer. May be you can get new variables there?

Comment: BTW do you need a way to add new fields in the enum as well?

Answer (score 0):

The [Fast Code Eclipse Plugin](http://fast-code.sourceforge.net/) looks like an option, but I got an error installing it which I don't have time to chase and the answer offered by user [qualidafial](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13253/qualidafial) on the question [Useful Eclipse Java Code Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028858/useful-eclipse-java-code-templates) does everything I need to do without requiring an Eclipse plugin.